# Changes to node_module not being reflected reactjs

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I'm working with `react-html-table-to-excel` and what I wanted to do was to change the style of the export button. So, I located the file in: `node_module/react-html-table-to-excel/src/ReactHTMLTableToExcel.jsx` and I changed it how I wanted.

However, when I save the file and refresh the browser, the changes aren't being reflected in the browser. To make sure, I even commented out the whole file and restarted the server and still no changes were made to the export button.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Two things: 1. Don't change what's in node_modules.  Your changes are going to vanish when you update the package.  2. If you want to see your changes take effect, those changes need to be recompiled.  `npm i` should do it.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks for the response. I tried npm i and still nothing changes.

Comment: You would need to restart your server after that too.

Comment: In simple terms it will work only on your local & those changes will not carry out to the server. This means other user will not carry that change as it is a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the style, better to update it in global *style.css* file of the project.

Do not change anything in node_modules. It's not your code. It's library code. It's third-party code. It's subject to being replaced/updated every time someone runs npm install, or clones your repo anew, or when the repo version updates. You have no way to even know if a particular file is used at run-time; the HTML file for a component's template probably is not. The package is a black box. Depending on how the library is packaged, the template may well have been pre-compiled in a build step run before the package was published.

Comment: Some of us use npx patch-package to safely manage updates to node_modules code, and aren't able to use a higher-level style.css or similar to make appropriate updates.

Comment: @dan674 Global style.css or any component level style file will work. You can add `!important` in few cases where your style rules do not reflect.

Comment: I'm changing components themselves in node_modules with patch-package as opposed to styles and css files. I'm also experiencing the problem described that "Changes to node_module not being reflected reactjs". As a result, "just use global style.css" isn't answering the question!